# "Because I since lost my move"

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrases

can you please explain what does this sentence mean '  Don't ask me to break because I  since lost my move"?

I think 'since' there is referred to the "starting point of time"  but I am not sure about it.
please check the link below for reference 
https://youtu.be/G5srTdVKjDI?t=3m45s

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In his interview with Oprah, Leonardo is asked

> Oprah: Is it true you almost quit acting when you were 11?
>   Leo: Yes because I was a break dancer (laughter)
>   Leo: **Don't ask me to break dance because I've since lost my moves**

in his answer "since" means

> *since the time that I was break dancing* I have forgotten my moves
>   *since the time that I stopped break dancing* I have forgotten my moves

Comment: meaning 'form that time on wards'? Thank you

Comment: Yes, from *some* time, whether *while* he was break dancing or after he *stopped* break dancing, it would not have be from when he *started* break dancing, because there would not have been a "since" for him to forget at the start, he would need to know *something* in order to forget it.